# Interrupção por timer - PIC18F4550

Tags: c, microcontrolador

Olá, sou estudante do curso Técnico em Mecatrônica. Meu professor passou um projeto para mostrarmos a velocidade de um motor CC com redução, em RPM, no Hyper Terminal. Ele falou que precisamos usar a interrupção por timer, porém, não entendi como se usa a interrupção por timer no PIC18F4550. Ele nos passou o programa base para só modificarmos para mostrar a velocidade. Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeceria muito.

Segue o programa base:

```
/*
Exemplo para controle de Motor de Corrente Contínua
*/
#include <18F4550.h>
#use delay(clock = 20MHz)
#fuses HS, NOWDT, PUT, NOBROWNOUT, NOLVP
#use rs232(baud = 9600, parity = N, xmit = pin_c6, rcv = pin_c7, bits = 8)
#include <stdlib.h>                  // biblioteca de conversão de valores
#define led       pin_e2
// Definição de nomes para os canais do encoder. Para determinação do 
sentido de giro,
// ao menos um dos canais deve ser conectado à algum pino de interrupção                 
externa
#define CanalB    pin_b1
// Definição de nomes para a seleção de sentido de acionamento da Ponte H
#define PonteH_1  pin_d0
#define PonteH_2  pin_d1

// Definição de variável(is) global(is)
int1 i1_Sentido;
int16 i16_iPWM = 0, i16_pPWM = 0;
float f_Resolucao = 0, f_Angulo = 0, f_Posicao = 0;
char s_Resolucao[4], s_Posicao[10], s_pPWM[4];
signed int16 Contador = 0;

// Declaração de funções utilizadas no programa
void PiscaLed(void)
{
// Pisca-pisca para led
output_high(led);
delay_ms(250);
output_low(led);
delay_ms(250);
return;
}
void Inicializacao(void)
{  
// Inicialização para controle do motor cc
printf("Resolucao do Encoder [ppv = pulsos por volta] = ");
gets(s_Resolucao);               // após <enter>, lê o valor do tipo string 
digitado
printf("\n\r");
f_Resolucao = atof(s_Resolucao);   // converte string em número do tipo 
float
f_Resolucao = 360/f_Resolucao;
delay_ms(250);
return;
}

// Declaração das interrupções e suas respectivas funções
#int_EXT
void  EXT_isr(void) 
{
// Este pedaço de código será executado se a interrupção for acionada, ou 
seja, o Canal A do encoder
// passar de nível Alto para Baixo [H_TO_L], conforme configuração no 
programa principal [void main()]
if ( !input(CanalB) )            // Se o Canal B estiver em nível Baixo -> 
Sentido Horário
{
  Contador--;
}
if ( input(CanalB) )            // Se o Canal B estiver em nível Alto -> 
Sentido Anti-Horário
{
  Contador++;
}
return;
}

// Função principal
void main()
{
PiscaLed();

// Configuração da(s) Interrupção(ões) Externa(s)
disable_interrupts(GLOBAL);         // Desabilita todas as interrupções se 
estiverem habilitadas
enable_interrupts(INT_EXT);         // Habilita a interrupção externa 0
ext_int_edge(0, H_TO_L);         // Configuração da interrupção externa para 
borda de descida :: High TO Low [H_TO_L]
                          // Se fosse borda de subida :: Low TO High 
[L_TO_H]
enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);         // Habilita todas as interrupções

// Configuração do sinal PWM
setup_ccp1(CCP_PWM);            // Configura CCP1 como um PWM
//   O tempo de ciclo (período, T) será dado pela seguinte expressão:
//      T = (1/clock)*4*t2div*(período+1)
//   onde:
//      T = período (será dado em segundos)
//      clock = clock configurado em <#use delay(clock = #)>
//      t2div = número de vezes de oscilação do cristal por instrução (pode 
ser: T2_DIV_BY_1 ou T2_DIV_BY_4 ou T2_DIV_BY_16)
//      período = valor que determina quando o valor de clock será resetado 
(pode ser um inteiro de 0 a 255)
//   Neste programa o clock é de 20MHz = 20000000Hz, t2div será por 16 
(T2_DIV_BY_16) e o período selecionado será de 249. Assim,
//      T = (1/20000000)*4*16*(249+1) = 0.0008s = 800us :: f = 1/T = 
1/0.0008 = 1250Hz (aprox. 1,25kHz)
setup_timer_2(T2_DIV_BY_16, 249, 1);// Configura o período T do sinal PWM

// Inicialização de escrita na porta serial
printf("\n\n\n\r");
printf("::...[ Curso Tecnico em Mecatronica ]...::\n\r");
delay_ms(250);
printf("::         Controle de Motor CC         ::\n\r");
printf("\n\r");
delay_ms(250);

Inicializacao();               // Chama função de inicialização do motor

while ( True )
{
  printf("\n\rDigite a posicao angular desejada: ");
  gets(s_Posicao);
  printf("\n\r");
  f_Posicao = atof(s_Posicao);
  delay_ms(250);

  printf("Digite o percentual de sinal PWM desejado [0 - 100]: ");
  gets(s_pPWM);
  printf("\n\n\r");
  i16_pPWM = atoi(s_pPWM);
  delay_ms(250);
  // Conversão do valor percentual de 0 a 100 para inteiro de 10bits
  i16_iPWM = i16_pPWM*10;         // 100% = 1000 :: 1000/100 = 10

  // Exemplo para uso do canal PWM: definição do tempo de ciclo ativo
  set_pwm1_duty(i16_iPWM);

  printf("PWM selecionado:  %5ld\n\r", i16_iPWM);
  printf("Posicao atual:    %5.1f\n\r", f_Angulo);
  printf("Posicao desejada: %5.1f\n\r", f_Posicao);
  if ( f_Posicao <= f_Angulo )
  {
     i1_Sentido = 0;
     printf("Sentido de giro:      Horario\n\r");
  }
  else
  {
     i1_Sentido = 1;
     printf("Sentido de giro: Anti-Horario\n\r");
  }

  if ( i1_Sentido == 0 )         // sentido horário
  {
     while ( f_Angulo > f_Posicao )
     {
        // Escrita/Acionamento do Motor CC
        output_high(PonteH_1);
        output_low(PonteH_2);
        f_Angulo = Contador*f_Resolucao;
        printf("Contador: %5ld :: Angulo: %5.1f\n\r", Contador, f_Angulo);
     }
     output_high(PonteH_1);
     output_high(PonteH_2);
  }

  if ( i1_Sentido == 1 )         // sentido anti-horário
  {
     while ( f_Angulo < f_Posicao )
     {
        // Escrita/Acionamento do Motor CC
        output_high(PonteH_2);
        output_low(PonteH_1);
        f_Angulo = Contador*f_Resolucao;
        printf("Contador: %5ld :: Angulo: %5.1f\n\r", Contador, f_Angulo);
     }
     output_high(PonteH_1);
     output_high(PonteH_2);
 }
 }
disable_interrupts(GLOBAL);         // Desabilita todas a interrupcoes 
externas se estiverem habilitadas
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No **PIC18F4550** temos 4 **TIMERS** embutido nele sendo os seguintes:

- Timer0 : 16-bit
- Timer1 : 16-bit
- Timer2 : 8-bit
- Timer3 : 16-bit

Dos quatro temporizadores no **PIC18F4550**, mostrarei **Timer1**. O trabalho dos demais temporizadores é o mesmo. Para gerar um atraso de tempo usando o Timer1, precisamos calcular uma contagem do tempo desejado.

**Etapas para programar o temporizador PIC18F4550**

1. Configure o registro T1CON.
2. Limpe o sinalizador de interrupção TMR1IF Timer1.
3. Carregue a contagem no TMR1 de 16 bits ou TMR1H (byte superior) e TMR1L (byte inferior).
4. Defina TMR1ON para iniciar a operação Timer1.
5. Aguarde TMR1IF = 1. Definir este bit como '1' mostra que a contagem do Timer1 ultrapassa de 0xFFFF a 0x0000.

**EXEMPLO**

Vamos gerar um atraso de 1 ms usando o **Timer1**.

```
#include "osc_config.h"     /* Configuration header file */
#include <pic18f4550.h>     /* Contains PIC18F4550 specifications */

#define Pulse LATB          /* Define Pulse as LATB to output on PORTB */

void Timer1_delay();

void main()
{
    OSCCON=0x72;        /* Configure oscillator frequency to 8MHz */
    TRISB=0;            /* Set as output port */
    Pulse=0xff;         /* Send high on PortB */

    while(1)
    {
        Pulse=~Pulse;       /* Toggle PortB at 500 Hz */ 
        Timer1_delay();     /* Call delay which provide desired delay */    
    }   
}

void Timer1_delay()
{
    /* Enable 16-bit TMR1 register, No pre-scale, internal clock,timer OFF */
    T1CON=0x80;  

    TMR1=0xf830;        /* Load count for generating delay of 1ms */
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON=1;     /* Turn ON Timer1 */
    while(PIR1bits.TMR1IF==0);  /* Wait for Timer1 overflow interrupt flag */
    TMR1ON=0;           /* Turn OFF timer */
    TMR1IF=0;           /* Make Timer1 overflow flag to '0' */
}
```

**Etapas para programar o temporizador PIC18F4550 usando interrupção**

1. Ative GIE, PEIE, TMR1IE.
2. Configure o registro T1CON.
3. Limpe o sinalizador de interrupção TMR1IF Timer1.
4. Carregue a contagem no TMR1 de 16 bits ou TMR1H (byte superior) e TMR1L (byte inferior).
5. Defina TMR1ON para iniciar a operação Timer1.
   6 .Quando TMR1IF = 1, o código salta para o ISR para executá-lo e, após o controle de execução, retorna ao programa principal.

**Programa**

```
#include <pic18f4550.h>
#include "Configuration_Header_File.h"

void Timer1_start();

#define Pulse LATB

void main()
{ 
    OSCCON=0x72;    /* Configure oscillator frequency to 8MHz */
    TRISB = 0;      /* Set as output Port */
    Pulse = 0xff;   /* Send high on PortB */
    Timer1_start();

    while(1);

}
/***************Interrupt Service Routine for Timer1******************/
void interrupt Timer1_ISR()
{

    TMR1=0xF856;
    Pulse = ~Pulse;     /* Toggle PortB at of 500 Hz */   
    PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;  /* Make Timer1 Overflow Flag to '0' */
}

void Timer1_start()
{
    GIE=1;      /* Enable Global Interrupt */
    PEIE=1;         /* Enable Peripheral Interrupt */
    TMR1IE=1;       /* Enable Timer1 Overflow Interrupt */
    TMR1IF=0;

    /* Enable 16-bit TMR1 register,no pre-scale,internal clock, timer OFF */
    T1CON=0x80;     

    TMR1=0xF856;    /* Load Count for generating delay of 1ms */
    TMR1ON=1;       /* Turn ON Timer1 */
}
```

Espero ter Ajudado.

Site Fonte: [electronicwings](https://www.electronicwings.com/pic/pic18f4550-timer)